# How many users visited two unique pages in one session?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Using google analytics I would like to find out how many users visited two specific pages in one session. I've tried using custom segments using a filter for both pages but I keep getting 0 session results which doesn't seem right.

For example: I want to know how many users visited '/user/register' and '/user/confirm/randomnumbersBlahBlahBlah' in the same session.

Can I reveal this with Google Analytics custom segments or any other method?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You are probably setting two filters in the conditions tab instead of using "and" (which works fine at least for me). Plus since this isn't about programming it's off-topic and should got to webmasters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about reporting, not programming.